# RT request tracker Can't able to get the tickets for query in Rest 2.0

Tags: rest

I tried to follow the  [RT REST Guide](https://metacpan.org/pod/RT::Extension::REST2#Example-of-plural-resources-(collections)) but i can't able to search tickets with query . Every time it is getting empty items . But i have tickets with all query and it is a valid token . All other api is working with this token

I used the command

```
curl -si  http://rt-test.backbonesecure.com/rt/REST/2.0/tickets?token=1-115-31ee899218dfb70735c500cd0a878857 -XPOST --data-binary '[{"field":"Status","value":"open"}]'

curl  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@abc.txt" -X POST http://rt-test.backbonesecure.com/rt/REST/2.0/tickets?token=1-115-31ee899218dfb70735c500cd0a878857
```

abc.txt contains the json query

```
{
"Queue": "General",
"Status": "new"
"Priority":"0"
"Owner":"Nobody"
}
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I am having luck using a query string. I haven't tried with a JSON search.

Firstly, I am quite sure that you are misusing the authentication token. It should be put into the header like [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/RT::Extension::REST2#Authentication). I would recommend you get a simple request working, like the queues/all example.

Here is the request that I send:

```
POST http://localhost/rt/REST/2.0/tickets
Authorization: token <REDACTED>
User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.15
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

query=subject = 'Test Subject';page=1
```

And the reponse back:

```
{
   "total" : 1,
   "count" : 1,
   "page" : 1,
   "items" : [
      {
         "type" : "ticket",
         "id" : "1415",
         "_url" : "http://localhost/rt/REST/2.0/ticket/1415"
      }
   ],
   "per_page" : 20
}
```